# Chilkat HttpResponse Cookies truncated

Tags: cookies, chilkat

1) Chilkat Lib Version : chilkat-9.5.0.79-x86-vc9

2) Send the following request :

```
   Request.put_HttpVerb("GET");

   Request.put_Path("/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=dexxxxxxx&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flogin.microsoftonline.com%2Fcommon%2Foauth2%2Fnativeclient&scope=openid%20offline_access%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2FFiles.ReadWrite%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2FFiles.ReadWrite.All&response_mode=query");

   Response = Http.SynchronousRequest("login.microsoftonline.com",443,true,Request);

    if (!Response)
    {
        printf("Http.SynchronousRequest error\r\n");
        return false;
    }
```

3) Obtained Response contains 5 Cookies :

```
Set-Cookie: buid=AQAxxxxxxgAA; expires=Fri, 08-Nov-2019 00:07:55 GMT; path=/; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=None
Set-Cookie: fpc=AmNJxxxx; expires=Fri, 08-Nov-2019 00:07:55 GMT; path=/; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=None
Set-Cookie: esctx=AQAxxxAA; domain=.login.microsoftonline.com; path=/; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=None
Set-Cookie: x-ms-gateway-slice=prod; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: stsservicecookie=ests; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
```

4) Trying to obtain cookies :

```
int iCookie = Response->get_NumCookies(); // iCookie = 5
const char *t0 = Response->cookieName(0); // "SameSite" obtained, not "buid"
const char *t1 = Response->cookieValue(0); // "None" obtained, not "AQAxxxxxxgAA"
```

5) Conclusion :
   Is this a bug ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks!  Seems to be a bug to me.  I'll find the problem, make the fix, and will post a link to a new build here..

Comment: Here's a new build that should solve the problem:  
https://chilkatdownload.com/prerelease/chilkat-9.5.0-x86-vc9-1594.zip

Comment: Can I have the following build too : chilkat-9.5.0-x86_64-linux-gcc, Thanks.